# Rename files in FTP using a single command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

To rename a File in a FTP using command line we need to do following.

```
ftp
open example.com
username
password
cd myfolder
rename myfile.txt mynewfile.txt
close
quit
```

So is there any command line or script logic where i can do it in a single line ?

Comment: Is this about Windows `ftp.exe`? Why do you need to do it on a single line? Do you need to use `ftp.exe`?

Answer (score 3):

You could create an FTP script file in which you list all your commands and execute it from your bat file in a single line like this:

Bat file:

```
FTP -v -i -s:C:\PathTo\ftpscript.txt
```

ftpscript.txt:

```
open example.com
username
password
cd myfolder
rename myfile.txt mynewfile.txt
disconnect
bye
```

Comment: This one i know. Is there any other commandline utility (ex: wget and wput which is single line command but it does not have rename option)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with `lftp`:

```
lftp -e 'mv fileA fileB; quit'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you download wget or curl (use chocolatey if on Windows) they both were created to solve this exact problem and to enable file transfer with a single line command for scripting purposes.

Curl example:

```
curl -T uploadfile ftp://upload.com/dir/ -Q "-RNFR uploadfile" -Q "-RNTO newfilename"
```